# Using CK Editor in symfony doesn't encode in utf8 in database

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, symfony-forms

I am trying to use CK editor bundle in my Symfony project to make an article editing system for the staff of my website. It's working but when I edit the text and i add some special characters like "é".

It doesn't convert them properly in my database an transform them in something like "é d&#39" and then shows those on the website instead of the "é".

See picture : [Image of the wrong characters showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqLCX.png)

I tried without CK editor with a regular TextAreaType input and it does convert them well, so the problem is definitely coming from CK editor.

How can I change the config to make it convert well in utf8 in the DB? I couldn't find anything on google.

Comment: PS: on the picture, on the left the one used editing with CK editor and the right one is with the regular TextArea which worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry it is my first post, no one answered.

Is it because my post doesn't match the standard or anything?

Or no one has an answer?